# RecyclerView перемещение на один элемент вперед

Tags: java, android

У меня есть горизонтальный `RecyclerView` и хотелось бы по бокам сделать стрелочки которые бы перемещали список на один элемент вперед, как этого добиться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте метод [scrollToPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#scrolltoposition).

```
myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Значение `position` можно вычислить например при обработке `onScroll`.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {           
        if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
        {
            visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            position = visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems; 
        }           
    }
});
```